# using 2 inputs or change type of input to show password

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a show password checkbox to my form.
When a user checks that checkbox password is shown.
Most of the examples that I found are using 2 inputs, one with `type="text"` and the other with `type="password"`. And switch between these inputs according to the status of the checkbox.
it is simpler to change type of input to `type="text"`, so why people use 2 inputs?

Comment: Yes!!..type="Password" can hide the character in the textbox

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.  Perhaps it's so that the `type="password"` is the only one that is submitted as the user may leave the other one on type="text" if they have shown it? Probably be easier to change the type back on submit though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably to make it work on old versions of IE, since IE 9 and below, do not allow dynamic change of `type="password"` to `type="text"`. it throws an error "Could not get the type property"

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with using type="text" as a way of showing the password, as it exposes the user to saving the password in plain text in their autocomplete settings.  I think the two input box approach is probably safer as you can stop the text one from being picked up by autocomplete by using autocomplete="off"

See this artcile describing the vulnerability: https://www.foxtonforensics.com/blog/post/uncovering-plain-text-passwords-in-internet-history

Answer (score 0):

**I hope ur trying to ask that u want single password input field and show password button...Below is my answer**

```
  <input type="password" name="passwd" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"  required="required">
 <input type="checkbox" id="showhide"/>
  <label for="showhide" id="showhidelabel">Show Password</label>




     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#showhide").click(function () {
     if ($("#txtPassword").attr("type")=="password") {
     $("#txtPassword").attr("type", "text");
     }
     else{
      $("#txtPassword").attr("type", "password");
     }
   });
  });
```

Comment: Sir, I know how to do it I am asking why others use 2 type of inputs to accomplish this. why not just change type as in your code

Comment: @Nuryagdy Mustapayev..Ive never seen anyone using 2 input fields for password...I hope u've seen amazon login form where they've implemented in the same manner..as soon as user enters the pwd user will be provided with another field to know what he as entered...Thats it another way of implementing it

Comment: https://codepen.io/felquis/pen/OPdaqK  here is the link and there is more examples that use 2 inputs

Comment: its just they are asking twice to enter password..one for pawd and another for repeat pwd...

Comment: @NuryagdyMustapayev....ya inspected it...Even ive implemented in the same manner in one of my applicaton....Its not compulsary to use both input type text and pwd....its left to coder...i hope ur satisfied...